# Can a macro access its own name?

Tags: tex-core

Can two macros - with the same body, so that comparison with `\ifx` would be true - have different behaviour depending on their name?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\red{some code for: if my name is red "red" else "not red" fi}
\let\blue\red
\begin{document}
\ifx\red\blue true \else false \fi %must give true
\red  %prints red
\blue %prints not red
\end{document}
```

I think the answer is no, but perhaps there is some trick I'm not aware of. Answers which work only for some engines are ok.

Comment: Does this redefined problem bear any relation to your interest, or not at all?  `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\testR[1]{\expandafter\if\expandafter\@gobble\string#1\R R\else Not R\fi}
\def\R{R}
\let\B\R
\ifx\R\B true\else false\fi\par
\testR\R\par
\testR\B
\end{document}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes no that's not my question. You use an outer macro \testR to check the name -- that is rather easy, I wanted to know if \R itself knows its name.

Comment: I figger'ed.  Just checkin'

Comment: would LuaTeX not be able to do this with some macro pre-processing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No. The macro must be expanded to reveal and execute the code. But the expansion replaces the macro token with the definition text, meaning the original macro is gone and no trace<sup>*</sup> is left that shows, where the code has come from.

<sup>*</sup> If `\tracingmacros` is active, then the `.log` file would tell the expansion step, but enabling `\tracingmacros` in the macro itself is too late. Also reading the `.log` file from within TeX is not as easy because the `.log` file block might not yet be written (buffered output/OS dependent behavior/...) and in the second run the `.log` file will be overwritten.

Answer (score 25):

I don't know the origin of this question (two macros are the same from
`\ifx` point of view and behaves differently with respect of their name).
But I would to present the way to modification of TeX source to solve this
task. I don't expect that somebody use this patch. This is only an
illustration how easy or hard such modification is. Let me start by
citation:

> Certainly, if I were in the publishing business myself, I would have
>   probably had ten different versions of TEX by now for ten different
>   complicated projects that had come in. They would all look almost the same
>   as TEX, but no one else would have this program--they wouldn't need it,
>   they're not doing exactly the book that my publishing house was doing.
>
> Donald E. Knuth, Prague, March 1996

We need to add the new primitive `\lastexpanded` which expands to the name
of the last expanded macro similar as `\string` does it. This means, that

```
\TeX \edef\a{\lastexpanded}  \edef\b{\string\TeX}
now: \a is equal to \b
```

We do this by creating `mytex.ch` change file. This is a "patch" to the 
`tex.web` source file. We start by intensively flipping through second
volume of C&T (TeX: The program) and by intensively thinking about it. 
Then we create the following file:

---

```
% This is a modification of TeX inspired by
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130285/has-a-command-access-to-its-own-name
% This modification adds new primitive \lastexpanded which expands to the
% \string of the last expanded macro name.

\S 297 declaration of global variables
@x
@!cur_tok: halfword; {packed representative of |cur_cmd| and |cur_chr|}
@y
@!cur_tok: halfword; {packed representative of |cur_cmd| and |cur_chr|}
@!lastexpanded_cs: pointer; {variable for \.{\\lastexpanded}}   
@!lastexpanded_chr: halfword; {|cur_chr| for \.{\\lastexpanded}}
@z

\S 389 macro_call saves its name
@x
warning_index:=cur_cs; ref_count:=cur_chr; r:=link(ref_count); n:=0;
@y
warning_index:=cur_cs; ref_count:=cur_chr; r:=link(ref_count); n:=0;  
lastexpanded_cs:=cur_cs; lastexpanded_chr:=cur_chr;
@z

\S 439 default values
@x
cur_val:=0; cur_val_level:=int_val; radix:=0; cur_order:=normal;
@y
cur_val:=0; cur_val_level:=int_val; radix:=0; cur_order:=normal;
lastexpanded_cs:=0; lastexpanded_chr:=0;
@z


\S 468 adding new expandable primitive \lastexpanded
@x 
@d job_name_code=pdftex_convert_codes {command code for \.{\\jobname}}
@y
@d job_name_code=pdftex_convert_codes {command code for \.{\\jobname}}
@d lastexpanded_code=pdftex_convert_codes + 1 {command code for
\.{\\lastexpanded}}
@z

@x
primitive("jobname",convert,job_name_code);@/
@!@:job_name_}{\.{\\jobname} primitive@>
@y
primitive("jobname",convert,job_name_code);@/
@!@:job_name_}{\.{\\jobname} primitive@>
primitive("lastexpanded",convert,lastexpanded_code);@/
@!@:lastexpanded_}{\.{\\lastexpanded} primitive@>
@z

\S 469 printing about new primitive
@x
  othercases print_esc("jobname")
@y
  lastexpanded_code:   print_esc("lastexpanded");
  othercases print_esc("jobname")
@z

\S 470 the c declaration
@x
@!c:number_code..job_name_code; {desired type of conversion}
@y
@!c:number_code..lastexpanded_code; {desired type of conversion}
@z

\S 471 Scanning argument, \lastexpanded has no argument
@x
job_name_code: if job_name=0 then open_log_file;
@y
job_name_code: if job_name=0 then open_log_file;
lastexpanded_code:  do_nothing;
@z

\S 472
@x
job_name_code: print(job_name);
@y
job_name_code: print(job_name);
lastexpanded_code: if lastexpanded_cs<>0 then sprint_cs(lastexpanded_cs)
  else print_char(lastexpanded_chr);
@z
```

---

The new expandable primitive is added in section 468. Here is a
little complication because our patch will be applied to the `pdftex`: there
are many new primitives and this is a reason why there is different value of the last code `job_name_code` than in the original TeX.
The global variables `lastexpanded_cs` and `lastexpanded_chr` are set in
`macro_call` procedure (section 389) and they are used in section 472 when
`\lastexpanded` is expanded.

Now, you can add the `mytex.ch` as the last item to the `pdftex_ch_srcs`
list in the `Makefile` in the `source/build/texk/web2c/` of the `pdftex` source.
Then you can run `make pdftex`. The new `pdftex` binary is compiled. You can
try:

```
 ./pdftex -ini
 **\relax
 *\show\lastexpanded
 > \lastexpanded=\lastexpanded.
```

You can generate the format `./pdftex -ini -jobname pdftex -etex pdfetex.ini`
and use it in the same directory by `./pdftex test`. The `test.tex` would be:

```
\edef\redname{\string\red}
\def\red{\edef\myname{\lastexpanded}%
    \ifx\myname\redname \message{I am RED}%
    \else  \message{I am NOT red}%
    \fi
}

\let\foo=\red

\red   % the output:  I am RED
\foo   % the output:  I am NOT red

\ifx\red\foo \message{YES}\fi   % the otput: YES

\end
```

Comment: ooh this patch is awesome! `:)`

Comment: Let’s start a campaign for having this primitive introduced in pdfTeX (edit: *all typesetting engines*)! :-D  I think that a better name would be `\lastexpandedmacroname`, though.

Answer (score 3):

Also as Heiko has said, it is not possible to do that using a macro by itself, I think it might be possible to do this using something that looks like a macro but is not.

The mean i think of would be do decide of a prefix character that would be applied to every color, and make this to be active. You would then be able to gobble the tokens of the color name from within that active character and do what you described.

For exemple, using "/" as the active character, you would then declare your color using

```
/red  % Gives "red"
/blue % Gives "not red"
```

Comment: If it isn't a real macro the `\ifx`-test will fail. Also the colors in my example were only for demonstration, in my actual problem I was investigating if I can tweak the behaviour of beamer in ignorenonframetext mode.

Comment: Hum, if you are specifically wanting to tweak something already existing, this sure couldn't help. 
Maybe you should insist a litle bit more on this constraint in your question. 
Also, i'm not really sure of what to do in that kind of case ... should I delete my answer ?