# Macros that know their macronames themselves?

Tags: macros

Some programming or scripting languages know the feature of `#0` or `$0`, holding the name of the current script or the current routine.

> Does a similar technique (or a workaround) exist for the macro name in
>   TeX/LaTeX?

To clearify my question:

Is it possible to extract the name of the macro in the macro itself in a helper macro, say `\CurrentMacroName`, for example macro/command `\FooBar` holds an internal `\def\CurrentMacroName{FooBar}` which only survives when `\FooBar` is expanded.

The reason, why I am asking is, that I want to provide some `\GenericWarning`/`\GenericError` messages inside my `\newcommand` definitions, referring to the current macro name without having to type again... I want to behave it generically -- of course, the individual message has to be adjusted for each command.

A small non-working example... (Perhaps working, if the `\CurrentMacroName` - technique does exist, but may have a different name)

```
\documentclass{article}

%% This is my favourite (if possible)
\newcommand{\FooBar}{%

%%% Definitions and typesetting commands here...

\GenericWarning{}{Warning from \CurrentMacroName} 
%%% other stuff
}

%%% Doing it the long way

\newcommand{\OtherFooBar}{%

%%% Definitions and typesetting commands here...

\GenericWarning{}{Warning from \OtherFooBar}    
%%% other stuff
}%


\begin{document}
\FooBar%

\OtherFooBar%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Short answer here is going to be 'no': TeX's a macro expansion language, so there is no concept of 'as long [as] `\FooBar` is executed'.

Comment: May be, as a workaround, renewcommand the `\newcommand` command, and add some sort of assignment to `\CurrentMacroName` at the beginning (you loose expandability).

Comment: @JosephWright: I struggled while writing...`expanded/executed`... I know the difference...

Comment: @Manuel: That's what I tried already, but failed. It's no good idea to fiddle around with `\renewcommand{\newcommand}`, it's like the bridge over Kazar-Dhum ;-)

Comment: @Manuel Expandablity is not an issue if you have the potential for a warning: this itself is not expandable, so you shouldn't assume the parent macro is.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130285/has-a-command-access-to-its-own-name

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That one's related, and I've linked, but I think this is not a dupe as there is a specific use case to cover: does that sound right?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks, I didn't look for `access`

Comment: @JosephWright: Yes it is related but I don't think that Christian needs the `\ifx` identity which I had as requirement.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've put a much my creative invention to my answer here (specially to the `\replacemacrobody` conversion) but I am not sure that this is usable. Suppose `\newcomand\A{...\A...}`. When somebody decides that `\B` is better than `\A` then he/she can replace both occurrences of `\A` to `\B` manually. He/she needn't to do the second replacing by automaton. Or I don't understand the question well?

Comment: @wipet: I am not sure that I understand your comment: My question was about the access of a macro to its name, for diagnostic purposes only

Comment: @ChristianHupfer More preciselly suppose `\newcommand\A{...\GenericWarning{}{Warning from \string\A}...}`. This means (more short) `\newcomand\A{...\A...}` from my prevous comment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

TeX is a macro expansion language: once a macro is expanded, there is no concept of being 'inside' it. As such, there is no stack or similar idea and you can't see where tokens 'came from'. (See [Has a command access to its own name?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130285/has-a-command-access-to-its-own-name) for more on this.)

The usual approach to the problem outlined is to have a secondary internal macro that does the work and set everything up in a semi-automated way. If we look for example at the LaTeX2e definition of `\mathrm` and this internal helper:

```
> \mathrm=macro:
->\protect \mathrm  .

> \mathrm =macro:
->\relax \ifmmode \else \non@alpherr \mathrm  \fi \use@mathgroup \M@OT1 \symoperators .
```

we see `\non@alpherr \mathrm`, and it's this that does the 'not in math mode' error if you don't have the command in the right place.

The final step is to define command so at the 'user' level you only give the name once. A typical construct would be to use a generator command and perhaps a generic error/warning with 'fill in the blank':

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mygenerator[2]{%
  \newcommand#1{%
    % Code here from #2
    \myerrorhelper#1%
  }%
}
\newcommand\myerrorhelper[1]{%
  \GenericWarning{}{Warning from \string#1}%
}
\mygenerator\mycommand{code}
\mygenerator\myothercommand{code}
\begin{document}
\mycommand
\myothercommand

\end{document}
```

Note that as warnings are not expandable, you might choose to use `\DeclareRobustCommand` for some or all of this.

Comment: Thanks! I had a similar idea in mind, but since I am lazy, I didn't want to write commands this way -- now I see, it has to be done like in your propositon. I also realize, that I am still thinking too much like a C etc. programmer, trying to force other concepts into TeX ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Understandable: macro expansion is very different from functional programming, and with catcodes as well TeX work needs a specific mindset!

Comment: Well, I hope, my mind is not too much functionally programmed already in order to switch over to learn the whole nine yards of macro expansion

Answer (score 8):

While my first attempt solves the task by replacing tokens at definition time, I can show another solution, where `\currcmd` is set at execution time. You can write:

```
\keepcurrcmd \newcommand \foo {... My name is \textt{\currcmd} ...}
```

and the macro `\foo` prints: ... My name is `\foo` ...

The `\keepcurrcmd` defines the macro `\foo` as

```
\edef\currcmd{\string\foo}\foo+currcmd
```

and the internal macro `\foo+currcmd` is defined by the original `\newcommand`.
The problem of this solution is that the `\foo` defined by this way isn't fully expanable even though the same `\foo` defined without `\keepcurrcmd` prefix is expanable.

The testing code follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\keepcurrcmd#1#2{%
   \def#2{%
       \edef\currcmd{\string#2}%
       \csname\string#2+currcmd\endcsname}%
   \expandafter#1\csname\string#2+currcmd\endcsname}

\keepcurrcmd \newcommand\testfirst {Text text.
   \GenericWarning{}{Warning from \currcmd}%
}
\keepcurrcmd \newcommand\testsecond [2] {Text, param #1, param #2.
   \GenericWarning{}{Warning from \currcmd}%
}

\begin{document}

Hello \testfirst,
\testsecond{paramA}{paramB}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The idea is to replace each occurrence of `\thiscsname` by the current `\name` in the macro body when the macro is defined by `\mynewcommand`. This means, that

```
\mynewcommand \mynameofmacro {... My name is \string\thiscsname ...}
```

would be replaced by

```
\newcommand \mynameofmacro {... My name is \string\mynameofmacro ...}
```

We can define \mynewcommand such a way:

```
\newtoks\macrobody
\let\newcommandOri=\newcommand
\def\mynewcommand#1#2#{%
   \def\macroname{#1}\def\macronameN{\noexpand#1}\def\newcommandparams{#2}%
   \afterassignment\mynewcommandA \macrobody
}
\def\mynewcommandA{%
   \replacemacrobody
   \edef\x{\noexpand\newcommandOri\macronameN\newcommandparams{\the\macrobody}}\x
}
```

The name of the macro is saved in `\macroname`, the parameters are saved in `\newcommandparams` and the macro body is saved in `\macrobody` toks register. The macro `\replacemacrobody` replaces in this toks register the occurrences of `\thiscsname` tokens to the contents of the `\macroname`. Finally, the `\newcommad` with the original LaTeX meaning is used via expanded `\x`. You can do `\let\newcommand=\mynewcommand` if you have bravery.

The core of this idea is the replacement macro which operates with `\macrobody` toks register. May be, you can use some LaTeX package to do this, but I don't know LaTeX, so I have to make this macro myself. This macro have to stay intact all tokens (spaces, `\bgroup`, `{`, `}`, `#`, etc.), only does `\thiscsname -> \name`. I am sorry, my implementation of this macro is somewhat complicated, but this works.

The whole example follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

%% The \replacemacrobody definition:
\newtoks\macrobody
\def\replacemacrobody{%
   \let\bgroup=\relax\macrobody\expandafter{\expandafter}\expandafter
   \replacemacrobodyA\the\macrobody\endmacrobody}
\def\replacemacrobodyA{\futurelet\tmp\replacemacrobodyB}
\def\replacemacrobodyB{%
   \let\next=\replacemacrobodyD
   \ifx\tmp\spacetoken \let\next=\replacemacrobodyC \addtomacrobody{ }\fi
   \ifx\tmp\thiscsname \let\next=\replacemacrobodyC
       \expandafter\addtomacrobody\macroname \fi 
   \ifx\tmp\endmacrobody \let\next=\replacemacrobodyE \fi
   \ifx\tmp\bgroupOri \let\next=\replacemacrobodyF \fi
   \next}
\def\replacemacrobodyC{\afterassignment\replacemacrobodyA \let\next= }
\long\def\replacemacrobodyD#1{\addtomacrobody#1\replacemacrobodyA}
\def\replacemacrobodyE{\ifx\IamInGroup\relax 
   \expandafter\endgroup \expandafter\macrobody\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      {\expandafter\the\expandafter\macrobody\expandafter{\the\macrobody}}%
   \afterassignment\replacemacrobodyA
   \else \let\bgroup=\bgroupOri \fi
   \let\next=}
\def\replacemacrobodyF{\begingroup\let\IamInGroup=\relax
   \afterassignment\replacemacrobody \macrobody=}
\long\def\addtomacrobody#1{\macrobody\expandafter{\the\macrobody#1}}
\let\bgroupOri=\bgroup
\def\tmp/{\let\spacetoken= }\tmp/ %
\def\thiscsname{^\thiscsname^}
\def\endmacrobody{^\endmacrobody^}


%% The \mynewcommand definition:
\let\newcommandOri=\newcommand
\def\mynewcommand#1#2#{%
   \def\macroname{#1}\def\macronameN{\noexpand#1}\def\newcommandparams{#2}%
   \afterassignment\mynewcommandA \macrobody
}
\def\mynewcommandA{%
   \replacemacrobody
   \edef\x{\noexpand\newcommandOri\macronameN\newcommandparams{\the\macrobody}}\x
}

\let\newcommand=\mynewcommand % I have bravery

%% The usage of redefined \newcommand:

\newcommand\testmacro
   {this is test\GenericWarning{}{Warning from \string\thiscsname}}
\newcommand\withparams [2]
   {this is \textbf{macro} with params: #1 and #2 
    \GenericWarning{}{Warning from \string\thiscsname}}

%% The test:

\begin{document}

\testmacro,
Macro \withparams {first}{second}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your effort is tremendous, but I fear, ways to complicated, on the other hand, if I could, I would your accept it as well, but I can't split my accept vote. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I hoped that somebody from LaTeX experts shows that the `\replacemacrobody` is already done in some LaTeX package (such as string.sty, expl3 or similar). My code can be very simplified if such hypothetical package is used.