# How to make the newcommand command use its own name as the name of a tikz node defined in its scope?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

It would be nice to have a simple way 
to avoid having to type (or copy) the string 
"nameofthenewcommand"
in the following 
code fragment

```
\newcommand{\nameofthenewcommand}{%
\node (nameofthenewcommand) [] {etc};
}
```

whose purpose is to be used in a large tikzpicture 
elsewhere in the code.

It would be nice to have something like

```
\newcommand{\nameofthenewcommand}{%
\node (rocn) [] {etc};
}
```

where rocn is a string I have just made up 
and which should be recognized by tikz as having 
the meaning "reflexion of the command-name", 
prompting it to substitute the string "nameofthenewcommand" 
in its stead.

What do you recommend to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Macros have no idea of their name, actually. See this question of mine, for example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195056/macros-that-know-their-macronames-themselves. You can use a command -defining macro to  track of the name

Comment: You are missing some `%` characters in your command

Comment: Thank you. Would you please clarify how in your opinion the "minimal" example I gave should be augmented by % characters? I will then edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Or feel free to edit my question accordingly.

Comment: I've added the `%` right after the `{` of the `\newcommand` definitions

Answer (score 2):

The command `\nodestuff` macro defines a wrapper command for a node definition and names the node like the macro.

However, this may not catch any of the possible `\node` calls and the usage is limited, in my point of view, since it is still necessary to remember the node name afterwards.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\nodestuff}[3][]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #2\endcsname{%
    \node[#1] (#2) #3;
  }%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \nodestuff[blue]{foo}{{$E=mc^{2}$}}
  \nodestuff[blue]{foobar}{ at (3,4) {$E=(mc^{2})^{2} + (pc)^{2}$}}
  \foo
  \foobar
  \draw  (foo) -- (foobar) node[midway,right] {A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I also appreciate that you added more options than what was being asked for. However, the motivation for the question is to keep the actual "front-end" of the tikzpicture as concise and humanly-readable as possible. I will therefore try to condense your example to a minimal approximation to my intial specification. Currently I do not have time to concentrate on this, but will come back to this question in a few days, and will delay accepting your answer until then.

Comment: @Christian +1 for your excellent work.

Answer (score 1):

In case you often face the task of creating a control sequence token via `\csname..\endcsname`, you can use TeX' `#{`-notation for defining a macro `\name` where tokens before the first opening brace are taken for an argument and where tokens nested into the first opening brace and the corresponding closing brace are taken for another/a second argument and where a control sequence token  is formed from the second argument before TeX processes the tokens from the first argument.

I elaborated on the `\name`-macro in the thread [Define a control sequence after that a space matters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338784) which was started at TeX - LaTeX StackExchange in November 10, 2016.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\name{}%
\long\def\name#1#{\UD@innername{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@innername[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{#1}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\makeatother

\newcommand{\nodestuff}[3][]{%
  \name\newcommand{#2}{%
    \node[#1] (#2) #3;
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \nodestuff[blue]{foonode}{{text at foonode}}
  \nodestuff[blue]{barnode}{ at (2,3) {text at barnode}}
  \foonode
  \barnode
  \draw  (foonode) -- (barnode);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you prefer to go the other direction, i.e., obtain the name from the control-sequence-token, you can have TeX apply `\string` and remove the preceding escape character if present. Be aware of edge cases like the value of the integer parameter `\escapechar` being 32/denoting a space.
Also the range of possible values where the integer parameter `\escapechar` yields producing a character token depends on the engine, i.e., depends on whether LuaTeX/XeTeX or "ordinary" TeX is in use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifxetex, ifluatex}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%

\newcommand\stringifysecond[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\romannumeral0\innerstringifysecond#2}{#1}%
}%

\newcommand\innerstringifysecond{%
  \ifnum\escapechar=32 \expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
  % In case escapechar is 32, you get a space as escapechar, thus do nothing
  % and have the space removed as terminator of the \romannumeral-expansion
  % that currently is in progress.
  {%
    \ifnum\escapechar<0 \expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
    {%
      \ifnum\escapechar>\ifxetex 1114111 \else\ifluatex 1114111 \else 255 \fi\fi
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo        
      \else
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \fi
      {%
        % There is a non-space escapechar, thus gobble that escapechar 
        % as undelimited argument and insert space for terminating \romannumeral:      
        \@firstofone{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter} \expandafter\@gobble
      }%
    }{%
      % There is no escapechar, thus just insert space for terminating \romannumeral:
      \@firstofone{\expandafter} %
    }%
  }%
  \string
}%
%
\newcommand{\nodestuff}[2][]{%
  \stringifysecond\innernodestuff{#2}{#1}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\innernodestuff[4]{%
  \newcommand#3{%
    \node[#2] (#1) #4;
  }%
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \nodestuff[blue]{\foonode}{{text at foonode}}
  \nodestuff[blue]{\barnode}{ at (2,3) {text at barnode}}
  \foonode
  \barnode
  \draw  (foonode) -- (barnode);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Let's look at the special case of the nameless node/nameless macro:

Stringifying the nameless control sequence token which in turn can come into being as the result of the expansion of the expression `\csname\endcsname` or can come into being due to tokenizing a backslash character/a character of category code 0 at the end of a line while the value of the integer parameter `\endlinechar` is negative or larger than 255 (ordinary TeX and XeTeX; with LuaTeX attempts of assigning values larger than 127 to `\endlinechar` yield error messages and don't get carried out) yields a sequence of character tokens of catcode 12(other) `\csname\endcsname`.

Answer (score 1):

The `\definenode` command takes as argument the node name, which makes a command from. See the examples; the new command will take as argument the coordinates for the node.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% syntactic sugar
\NewDocumentCommand{\newnamecommand}{m}
 {
  \exp_args:Nc \newcommand{#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\definenode}{mom}{%
  % #1 = command (no backslash)
  % #2 (optional) = optional argument to \node
  % #3 = replacement text
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {\newnamecommand{#1}[1]{\node (#1) at ##1 {#3};}}
   {\newnamecommand{#1}[1]{\node[#2] (#1) at ##1 {#3};}}%
}

% \foo will expand to "\node (foo) at #1 {$E=mc^2$};"
\definenode{foo}{$E=mc^2$}
% \baz will expand to "\node[blue] at #1 {Energy};"
\definenode{baz}[blue]{Energy}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foo{(0,0)}
  \baz{(3,4)}
  \draw  (foo) -- (baz) node[midway,right] {A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]