# Is it possible to get rid off of { and } in the definition of a command?

Tags: macros, strings

My purpose is to write simple commands that put graves and other accents symbols above Greek letters. I am facing the following problem: Let say `\grave{i}` puts the grave symbol above I (for example: `ka\grave{i}`). It would be more easy for me not to use `{ }` something like `ka\gravei`. So my question is: Is it possible to get rid off `{ }` from the definition of a command? (For example `\gravearea` should output area with a grave on the first letter i.e. `a`. ) Also, I don't like the use of spaces, like `\gravea rea` because they divide the words...

Comment: Have you tried `\grave area`?

Comment: @Werner Thank you for the corrections. Yes I tried! There are many times that I need  to put one or more  accents in the midlle of a word. So again I have to divide the word. It would much more usefull to not to use space at all! For example I prefer   gr\ta\teal (where \t put a vertical accent on the next letter) instead gr\t a\t eal

Comment: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=26836&view=unread#unread LaTeX, as a computer program, is dumb as hell and does not know what belongs to the control sequence and what doesn't. A space (or other nonletter) is the only way to mark the end.

Comment: @kornaros: Short answer. In you example, imagine what would happen if `\t`, `\te`, `\tea` are all macros. How would TeX figure out if you mean `gra\t{a}\t{e}al` or `gra\t{a}\te{a}l` or `\gra\t{a}\tea{l}`?

Comment: If it is only for accents, you can use `\'a` or the other similar command

Comment: @Aditya Yes one have to be very careful with such definitions! You have to define these commands inside a suitable enviroment.  A  better Idea should be the development of a special enviroment like \begin{greekaccents}  gra\ta\teal \end{greekaccents} for working with these symbols. I find this idea very practical because there many times that one have to rewrite a monototic text to a polytonic text with the easiest possible way i.e. just inserting some \t , for example,  in the miidle of the words. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: @kornaros You can exploit `babel` shorthands (see the `babel` manual for details)

Comment: @Roman Picot. Writing or trasforming a monotonic greek text to polytonic text for scholar use is not a simple case at all! There are hundreds of possible accents combinations that one has to consider. I have no problem to write all these commands...My problem is that I dont like to make the paragraphs and the words  very difficult to read or find mispellings because of the heavy use of { } or spaces etc. in the middle of  words!

Comment: I agree with you that accent commands make test less readable, that's why I don't input `Gr\"{u}\ss e`  but `Grüße` and use  inputenc (or one of the utf8-engines xelatex/lualatex). Naturally I have chars like üäö on my keyboard, but I'm rather certain that a greek keyboard offers the means to input politonic accents.

Comment: @yo' These shorthands (with the use of > or < , | , ', " , ~ and other common symbols ) make the source code(the greek text) very unreadable! Instead of write >'aneu it would be much more prefereable to use a single command like \taneu

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer The problem arise if you have to transform a big text like a poem etc to polytonic. It is very hard to remember all these keyboard combinations instead of using some \ commands that are very easy to remember!

Comment: @Johannes_B You are right! A space or other nonletter symbol marks the end of a command. I will try to refrase my question. Is it possible to make an enviroment such that  TeX  accepts any command that starts with the word grave like \gravearea \graveareal \graveareali etc and outputs the part of the string after the word grave with a grave on its first letter?

Comment: No, the command has no access to its own name: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130285/has-a-command-access-to-its-own-name. You can't use words like "grave" for your wanted input. You must use a "nonletter".

Comment: `\grave` is a _math_ accent in text the command is `\\``  which can be used without braces or space.

Comment: @Ulrike_Fischer. Oh ! that is  a problem...  I am wondering if one could change a "strange" unicode character to a "nonletter" character to be used as a control character...

Answer (score 4):

You can do this if the letter is not a letter. Anytime TeX reads the sequence:

```
<backslash><valid_nonletter>
```

(this is in the standard setting; "valid" means basically any printable ASCII character), then TeX interprets it as the control character and executes it, **no matter whether a space follows.** So you could use for instance:

```
 gr\7a\7eal
```

With `\7` defined in the preamble by:

```
\let\7\t
```

***Note that I do not consider this a good idea, but you asked for it.*** Also, please, do not use anything like this in files you will provide to anybody like journals, publishers, collaborators etc.

Comment: You are right! I am thinking of developing a new enviroment let say \begin{greekaccents} .....\end{greekaccents} for working locally with these commands. Could you please impove your answer such that \let\7\t works only locally? Also is it possible to have  a string of characters like grave as a single "control" character inside the inveroment?

Comment: `\newenvironment{greekaccents}{\let\7\t}{}` -- just hide the `\let` in the group formed by the environment. Sorry I gotta go, will be back late at night (CET).

Comment: @kornaros, instead of fighting with weirdly written words due to TeX-speak for accents, just use e.g. UTF8 and write the accented characters directly. It might cost a bit in setup (LaTeX system and also e.g. keyboard/display), but it is definitely worth it.

Comment: @kornaros -- it is *not* possible to treat a string of letters as a single character.  a control sequence is defined by tex as (1) a backslash followed by one or more letters up to the next non-letter, or (2) a backslash followed by a single non-letter.  to change this, one would have to redesign and re-implement tex itself.

Comment: @barbara Thank you for the explanation! You gave me an idea! Is it possible to make a non letter character as a control character inside a special enviroment without the use of  additional \ ? Like using  @ etc. instead the command \7 above? In other words Is it possible something like gr@a@eal to work??

Comment: @kornaros Yes, that _is_ possible. One way how to do it is using babel shorthands -- they _need not be two characters_, they can be one-character shorthands only.