# Retrieve a command name from inside its code

Tags: macros, tex-core

Is there a trick (some unkown primitive ?) to getting the name of a command from inside the code that makes up that command, something like `\thiscommandname` or the like ?

Comment: no, this information is not available

Comment: `\newcommand\steve{Hi, my name is \string\steve}` but not otherwise. If your macro's name gets built by `\csname` and you're using LuaTeX you can also use `\lastcsname`, so `\newcommand\steve{Hi, my name is \expandafter\string\lastcsname}\csname steve\endcsname` will work.

Comment: Anyway, you should never put yourself in a situation where this is necessary. It sounds like an XY problem to me. If you really absolutely need this, you can create a custom command, `\mynewcommand`, which saves the name as `\thiscommandname` and then runs `\newcommand`. But I don’t really see the use for it.

Comment: You can do `\def\foo{whatever}` and then `\let\baz\foo`. What name should be returned when you call `\baz`? Well, the example shows why this is not possible: with `\let` TeX only makes a pointer to a certain location of memory where the definition is stored. Different control sequences can point to the same location. And the pointer associated to `\foo` might change to another location with a later `\def\foo{something else}`.

Comment: @egreg Technically, one could imagine the TeX engines being extended so that your example would return `\baz`. I don’t see how this would lead to any inconsistencies.

Comment: @Gaussler No, the memory location doesn't know what its “outside name” is as several control sequences can point to it.

Comment: Had a mix-up in my head somehow, should be `\lastnamedcs` not `\lastcsname` in LuaTeX.

Comment: @egreg As I said, with appropriate *extensions* to the TeX engines, it would be possible.

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130285/2388

Comment: The answers to [What would be the drawbacks of adding #0 for denoting the name of the macro that currently is expanded?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/506752/118714) might be of interest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would be the drawbacks of adding #0 for denoting the name of the macro that currently is expanded?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506752/what-would-be-the-drawbacks-of-adding-0-for-denoting-the-name-of-the-macro-that)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a macro access its own name?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130285/can-a-macro-access-its-own-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike functions in a compiled language, there is no scope attached to a macro; it is simply replaced inline by its unevaluated replacement text and processing continues from the start of the replacement. So it would be rather unnatural to have a command that changed its expansion at the end of a replacement, and tex does not provide that information in an accessible way, although it does show essentially the stack of open replacements in the context lines in an error message.

```
\def\a{aaa\b ccc}
\def\b{xxx \q yyyy}
\def\q{ ggg \RROR}

\a

\bye
```

Produces

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\q -> ggg \RROR 
                
\b ->xxx \q 
            yyyy
\a ->aaa\b 
           ccc
l.6 \a
      
?
```